# Entrar a página a través de clave con botón y enter

Tags: login, input

Creé una clave se acceso para entrar a una página con un botón. Tambien quiero entrar a la página dando enter como entro clickeando el boton. ¿alguien me puede ayudar con eso?

```
           <fieldset id="form-ingreso">
                    <form id="contrasena" name="form" action="INICIO SESION">
                        <input id="clave" type="password" name=password placeholder="Ingrese la contrasena">
                        <input class="boton_form" id="btn"  type=button value="ENTRAR AL RETIRO">
                    </form>
                </fieldset>


<script>
function ir(){
let c=108;
if(document.form.password.value==c){

window.location="OnePage.html";}
else{
alert('Contrasena incorreta');
}
}
const entrada = document.getElementById('btn')

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){

  entrada.addEventListener('click', ir)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar un form, si el botón es de tipo `"submit"`, la tecla Enter automáticamente realiza el equivalente a pulsar el botón (una acción submit):

```js
function ir(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let c = "108";
  if(document.form.password.value === c){
    console.log("Correcto!");
  }else{
    console.log("Contrasena incorreta");
  }
}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', ir)
})
```

```html
<fieldset id="form-ingreso">
    <form id="contrasena" name="form" >
        <input id="clave" type="password" name=password placeholder="Ingrese la contrasena">
        <input class="boton_form" id="btn"  type="submit" value="ENTRAR AL RETIRO">
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Gracias pablo, llevo dias quemandome las neuronas tratando de hacerlo desde javascript. que por cierto no es mi fuerte, para nada.